# HitHighlightedSummary HitHighlightedProperties is empty in people search using REST

Tags: rest, user-profile-property, people-search, sharepoint-on-prem

Is there a way to get search hits in

- HitHighlightedSummary
- HitHighlightedProperties

on **people search** using REST?

> /_api/search/query?querytext=%27ers%27&sourceid=%27b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31%27&selectproperties=%27UserName,FirstName,LastName,HitHighlightedProperties,HitHighlightedSummary,Office%27

I only get empty properties..

```
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
   <d:Key>HitHighlightedProperties</d:Key>
   <d:Value m:null="true"/><d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>

<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
  <d:Key>HitHighlightedSummary</d:Key><d:Value/>
  <d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
```

Sharepoint 2013 on-prem

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, if I enter no searchproperty I have HitHighlightedSummary but if I define it with the summary it returns null. Have you solved it?

I found it. Apparently you should seperate them;

```
SelectProperties: ['ListItemID', 'Title', 'Path', 'Description', 'SPWebUrl', 'contentClass', 'IsContainer', 'PictureThumbnailURL', 'HitHighlightedSummary'],
```

this was the old one

```
SelectProperties: ['ListItemID, Title, Path, Description, SPWebUrl, contentClass, IsContainer, PictureThumbnailURL, HitHighlightedSummary'],
```

Also this query works for me:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='search'&SourceId='32e1c04c-651b-4dfb-a240-ddc5332decff'&selectproperties=%27Title,HitHighlightedProperties,HitHighlightedSummary%27
```

Comment: Sorry a bit new here, thanks for help